# How to set min-height of div to fit the screen?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.banner{
    width:800px;
    height:160px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
.main_box{
    width:800px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner"></div>
<div class="main_box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here when I set the min-height of `main_box" to 100%`  nothing happens.

But when I set it's height in pixels, the height is visible. I want to set the height of `main_box` div to fit the screen.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: _“Here when I set the min-height of "main_box" to 100%, nothing happens”_ – of course not, because any height given in percentages must have a height set for the parent element as well, otherwise it is unclear what value to take a percentage of in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use ([viewport-units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)) `vh` [Sizing with CSS3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/)'s vw and vh units

```
min-height: 100vh
```

full code

```css
.banner{
    width:800px;
    height:160px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
.main_box{
    width:800px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    background:red
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"></div>
<div class="main_box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First set html, body height to 100%

```
html,body{
    height:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this css:

```
<style>
html,body{
    height:100%
}
.banner{
    width:800px;
    height:160px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
.main_box{
    width:800px;
    min-height:300px;
    height:75%;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
```